# How to write a select query for this

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two table like this

```
job(id,title,location,...)

job_page(id,id_job,id_page,page_name)
```

For example I want to write a select query to fill a table with following columns:

```
+_______+________+__________+_______+
|Job Id | Titlte | Location | Page  |
+_______+________+__________+_______+
|1      | Hot job| Somewhere| Page1 |
|       |        |          | Page2 |
+_______+________+__________+_______+
```

How can I write a select query for this?

I tried but it's not as I expected:

```
SELECT jp.page_name,j.* FROM jobs j
LEFT JOIN job_pages jp ON jp.id_job = j.id
GROUP BY j.id;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `group_concat`:

```
 SELECT j.id, j.title, j.location, group_concat(jp.page_name)
 FROM jobs j LEFT JOIN job_pages jp ON jp.id_job = j.id
 GROUP BY j.id, j.title, j.location;
```

In MySQL, you can abbreviate the GROUP BY:

```
 SELECT j.id, j.title, j.location, group_concat(jp.page_name)
 FROM jobs j LEFT JOIN job_pages jp ON jp.id_job = j.id
 GROUP BY j.id;
```

but this really bugs multi-database users like me.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you'd like to put all the "pages" into a single cell. I guess the only thing you are missing is [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) on j.page_name . If it is for web or something, you may also use SEPARATOR clause set to <br /> or something.